# What is the Lebesgue measure of the set of numbers in $[0,1]$ that has two thirds of ones in their infinite base-2 expansion?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $S= \{x \in [0,1 ]: \lim_{n \to \infty }  \frac {1 } {n } \sum _{i=1 } ^n d _i (x) = 2/3 \} $, where $d _i(x) $ gives the ith digit of the infinite base-2 expansion of $x $. What is the Lebesgue measure of $S $?

First I want to prove that $S $ is a measurable set, and secondly determine its measure.

---

$d _i(X) : [0,1 ]\mapsto \{0,1 \} $,

$d _1^{-1 }  (0)= [0,1)$
$d _1^{-1 }  (1)=\{1\}  $
$d _2^{-1 }  (0) = [0,\frac {1 } {2 }  )$...

So that $d _i $ is a measurable map? Now the sum is nondecreasing and bounded, hence converges pointwise. Thus the sum is a measurable map? Hence $S $ is measurable?

If my reasoning is correct, then what is the measure?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know that the $d_i$ are stochastically independent random variables? Do you know the (strong) law of large numbers?

Comment: I know the strong law of large numbers, not what stochastically independent means, but please refere me and I will read...

Comment: Saw now that stochastically independent is just an other name for idependent... How can $d _i $ be seen as stochastic variables?

Comment: You interpret $([0,1], \mathcal{B}, \lambda)$ as a probability space, where $\mathcal{B}$ is the $\sigma$-algebra of Borel sets (or Lebesgue measurable sets if you wish) and $\lambda$ is Lebesgue measure. Then $d_i : [0,1] \to \{0,1\}\subset\Bbb{R}$ is a measurable map, i.e. a random variable.

Comment: @PhoemueX Thanks, but I cannot show independence. I believe I should show that for any $i,j $ and $a,b \in \{0,1\} $, $\mu(d _i^{-1 } (a)\cap d _j^{-1 } (b))=\mu(d _i^{-1 } (a)) \mu(d _j^{-1 } (b))$

Comment: But for say $a,b =0 $ i get $\mu(d _i^{-1 } (0)\cap d _{i+1 } ^{-1 } (0))=2^{-i+1 } \neq \mu(d _i^{-1 } (0))\mu ( d _{i+1 } ^{-1 } (0))=2^{-i }$ ?

Comment: First of all, you always have $\mu(d_i^{-1}(0))=1/2=\mu(d_i^{-1}(1))$ for all $i$. What I did not note in your first post that you incorrectly calculated the $d_1^{-1}$ sets. You have $d_1^{-1}(0)=[0,1/2)$. Finally, you will need to show what you have written not only for every **pair** of $i,j$ (or for $i,i+1$), but for any finite family.

Comment: @PhoemueX Ok, still having problem with this. How can I show that if $\cup _{i=I }d _i^{-1 } (a _i) $ is nonempty (I a finite index set), then its intersection with $d _j^{-1 }  (a )$ is half the size ( or empty)?

Comment: See this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1067585/how-can-i-show-that-the-binary-digit-maps-b-i-0-1-to-0-1-are-i-i-d.