# A limit set defined in terms of the dyadic expansion

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Consider the dyadic expansion for numbers on the unit interval.

Let $A_n=\left\{x\colon d_{n+1}(x)=\dots=d_{2n}(x)=0\right\}$, where $d_k(x)$ is the $k$th dyadic digit.

I want to find $A=\lim_n A_n$ and to prove that it has Lebesgue measure $0$.

What I've tried so far is to consider the dyadic expansion for $x_a\in A_n$. It will be of the form

\begin{align}
x_{a_n}=&\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{d_i}{2^i}+\sum_{i=2n+1}^{\infty}\frac{d_i}{2^i}
\end{align}

from there I argued that when $n\to \infty$ the last term vanishes, and I thought the limit set are all numbers with a terminating expansion, which are therefore a subset of $\lbrack0,1\rbrack\cap\mathbb{Q}$ and hence are countable and have Lebesgue measure 0. But I'm not so sure anymore.

Is this correct?

Comment: This might be helpful for simplifying the proof:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1067585/how-can-i-show-that-the-binary-digit-maps-b-i-0-1-to-0-1-are-i-i-d. Also, you do not to determine the limit set explicitly. It will be enough to show that the measure goes to zero fast enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found what I was looking for.

A little thought should be enough to realize that the $k$-th digit of the dyadic expansion is zero on the set

\begin{equation}
B_k=\bigcup_{i=1}^{2^{k-1}}\left\lbrack \frac{2(i-1)}{2^k},\frac{2\left(i-1\right)+1}{2^k} \right).
\end{equation}

Now, what I need is the intersection, namely

\begin{align}
A_n=& B_{n+1}\cap \dots \cap B_{2n}\\
=& \bigcup_{i=1}^{2^{n}}\left\lbrack \frac{2^n(i-1)}{2^{2n}},\frac{2^n\left(i-1\right)+1}{2^{2n}} \right).
\end{align}
I figured this out with help of a drawing. Since every subinterval has length $1/2^{2n}$, we get

\begin{align}
\lambda \left(A_n\right)=& 2^n\frac{1}{2^{2n}}\\
=& \frac{1}{2^n}
\end{align}

and $\lambda(A_n)\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$.