# Construct sequence of independent random variables on the Lebesgue measure

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, independence

Let (Ω, A, P) = ([0 , 1), B [0 , 1) , λ), where B is the Borel sigma algebra and λ the Lebesgue measure.

How do I construct a sequence of independent random variables $X_n$?

Comment: What have you tried? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: See here for one example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1067585/how-can-i-show-that-the-binary-digit-maps-b-i-0-1-to-0-1-are-i-i-d For another example, take all $X_n =0$.